# performSelector: didn't work properly when using dispatch_async and global_queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to ask is there some underlying reason that performSelector: method need its own runloop timer to work properly, because if i don't set a runloop especially for him , he will quit his job!

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    NSLog(@"touchesBegan --- %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    dispatch_async((dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)), ^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

/**
*  uncomment this line to make it work
*/
       // [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

    });

}

-(void)test
{
    NSLog(@"test --- %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
}
```

Comment: "he will quit his job!" haha.. you made my day.. thank you.. :D :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you must need to call your selector in `dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});`. Please see the code below.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

NSLog(@"touchesBegan --- %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    dispatch_async((dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)), ^{
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //ADDED THIS LINE
            [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
            //[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
        });//ADDED THIS LINE
    });
}
```